# Google SPDY - Has anyone used it on Apache?

Tags: apache, http, spdy

Just wondering if anyone has had any experience with Google SPDY on Apache? http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/

I run a couple of web servers and am interested to know if there have been any issues with the mod_spdy Apache module and if anyone has seen a visible speed increase in SPDY supported browsers?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/354129/google-spdy-has-anyone-used-it-on-apache

Answer (score 2):

I just installed it a few hours ago and it seems to work for me. You can see my blog post on the experience here: http://ddevnet.net/blog/2012/04/23/apache-mod_spdy-spdy-protocol-apache/

The only "problem" I had was turned out to be an unnecessary redirect in one of my virtualhosts.

As for a "visible increase" I would say that it is not really perceptable to the end user for the majority of webpages. Pages with a lot of scripts, images and cookies may have a large difference. I could imagine that you would notice the difference on a long forum post.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen my google home page load faster when I enabled SPDY on Firefox (change that setting in-about:config). Here is a link to an explanation of SPDY (podcast link here as well, but this link is to the HTML transcript only so you don't have to download a whole podcast). Hope this helps, they talk a bit about apache, but mostly about SPDY itself.

http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-343.htm